# Similar matrices and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I guess that I'm missing here something...

How to prove that, if two matrices are similar, then their minimal polynomials are the same one.

Thanks!

Comment: As a rough idea: think of the conjugation action on matrices as an automorphism. Then this statement becomes clear. :D

Comment: If $A=PBP^{-1}$, you have $f(A)=Pf(B)P^{-1}$ for every polynomial $f$. So $f(A)=0$ if and only if $f(B)=0$. Hence the annihilating ideals in $K[X]$ are the same. So they have the same monic generators which are, by definition, the minimal polynomials. More down to earth: observe that the minimal polynimals divide each other from the equivalence $f(A)=0$ iff $f(B)=0$.

Comment: What are  *annihilating ideals*?

Comment: The annihilating ideal of $A$ is the set of all polynomials $f$ such that $f(A)=0$. Or the kernel of $f\longmapsto f(A)$, if you prefer. It is of the form $f(X)K[X]$ (in your case, I assume your matrices are over fields, in which case $K[X]$ is principal). The only monic $f$ for which this holds is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, if the ideal approach is too involved, just do like this. Let $f_A$ and $f_B$ be the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $B$. Then $f_A(A)=0$ implies $f_A(B)=P^{-1}f_A(A)P=0$. So $f_B$ divides $f_A$. Likewise, $f_A$ divides $f_B$. So $f_A=f_B$, as they are monic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minimal polynomials are defined for linear operators $\phi:V\to V$ on a finite dimensional vector space. The minimal polynomial of a square matrix is that of a linear operator it represents on some basis. Two square matrices are similar if and only if they represent the same linear operator $\phi:V\to V$, each in a basis of $V$. End of proof.

Since julien questioned this point, let me elucidate the second sentence. I did not say that the minimal polynomial of a square matrix is *defined as* that of a linear operator it represents on some basis. But it is easily seen to be equal to it. Let $\def\B{\mathcal B}\B$ be an ordered basis of $V$, with $n$ elements. The map $\def\Mat{\operatorname{Mat}}\def\End{\operatorname{End}}\Mat_\B:\End(V)\to M_{n,n}(k)$ that sends a linear operator to its matrix with respect to$~\B$ is an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces and of rings (since that is how matrix multiplication is defined). Let $\phi\in\End(V)$ and $A=\Mat_\B(\phi)\in M_{n,n}(k)$. Let $f_1:K[X]\to\End(V)$ be the substitution morphism of $\phi$ for $X$ (sending $P(X)\mapsto P(\phi)$ if you will, though I abhor of this notation) and let $f_2:K[X]\to M_{n,n}(k)$ similarly be substitution of $A$ for $X$. By definition the minimal polynomial of $\phi$ is the monic polynomial of minimal degree in $\ker f_1$, and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the monic polynomial of minimal degree in $\ker f_2$. Now the diagram commutes, $f_2=\Mat_\B\circ f_1$, since both sides are the same on $K$ and on the element $X$, by the universal property of polynomial rings. But since $\Mat_\B$ is an isomorphism, $\ker(f_1)=\ker(f_2)$, so the minimal polynomials are equal. "Look mom, no conjugations!". All this may seem a lot of learned language, but it just amounts to saying that matrices do what they are supposed to do, allow concretely determining properties of linear maps.

A final remark: the above is based on the fact that minimal polynomials can be defined without having to introduce matrices. While this is easy to see, it is not something insignificant. By comparison, I don't think there is any simple way to define the *characteristic* polynomial without introducing matrices.

Comment: "The minimal polynomial of a matrix is that of a linear operator it represents on some basis". This is a well-defined definition of the minimal polynomial of a matrix from the minimal polynomial of a linear transformation, precisely because of the result that the OP is asked to prove.

Comment: @julien: I've extended the answer to address your concern.

Comment: Unlike the previous question on eigenvalues, I find that this time you are making things way more complicated than they are. If we define the minimal polynomial, for matrices and for linear operators, as the monic generator of the annihilating ideal. Then this is invariant under similarity because the ideals are trivially the same. In both cases. And sure, the minimal polynomial of an operator coincides with the one of any of its matrix representations. It is not a shortcut to consider the operator represented by the matrix. "I abhor"...wow!

Comment: Sorry, I've just checked "opinionated" in the dictionary and that's not what I meant. Just: a majority of people write $P(\phi)$ when $\phi$ belongs to a $K$-algebra and $P$ is a polynomial in $K[X]$. And I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @julien: Whether simpler or not is a matter of taste; viewed at a higher level the argument is basically the same. But I prefer not to work _inside_ $M_{n,n}(K)$ since it gives you the opportunity to make silly mistakes, like conjugating in the wrong direction. A choice of basis defines just _one_ isomorphism from endomorphisms to matrices, there is no way of tripping up here. As for $P(X)$, I _know_ that this is what people write, and that is why I used it, sparing you the notation that I prefer. I could give a list of reasons why I abhor, but that's not the point here.

Comment: On second thoughts, after a good lunch, I really like your intrisic approach of this easy fact, +1. As you say, it is just a matter of taste. I confess I like the computational convenience of $f(PAP^{-1})=Pf(A)P^{-1}$. Regards.

Comment: The maps $\mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}$, $f_1$, and $f_2$ are all $K$-algebra homomorphisms, correct?

Comment: @justin: Yes, that is correct.