# Prove that if $A,B$ are similar matrices then they have same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that if $A,B$ are  similar matrices then they have same minimal polynomial.

**My try**:

We have $B=PAP^{-1}$ for some $P$.

Let the minimal polynomial of $A$ be $m_A(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots +a_nx^n$

and the minimal polynomial of $B$ be $m_B(x)=b_0+b_1x+\ldots +b_mx^m$.

Now, $m_B(B)=0\implies b_0I+b_1(PAP^{-1})+\ldots +b_m(PA^mP^{-1})=0\implies P(b_0I+b_1A+b_2A^2+\ldots b_mA^m)P^{-1}=0\implies b_0I+b_1A+b_2A^2+\ldots b_mA^m=0\implies m_B(A)=0$.

Hence $m_A(x)|m_B(x)$.

Also charcteristic polynomials of $A,B$ say $C_A(x),C_B(x)$are same.

Now $m_B(x)|C_B(x)=C_A(x)$.Also $m_A(x)$ is the smallest degree monic polynomial which divides $C_A(x)$.Also $m_B(x)|C_A(x)$.

Hence $m_B(x)=m_A(x)$

Please check whether the proof is correct or not.Really need some help.

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/356039)

Comment: I would say it's easier, after $m_A\mid m_B$, to say "And analogously, we get $m_B\mid m_A$, so they must be equal."